# How to detect if a variable is not changing for a certain period of time?

Tags: jquery, html, websocket

I want detect if machine is idle for 15s and if so a popup show. when data is coming from the server my variables do a mathematical calculation and change the value. so what I want is if this variable doesn't change for 15s a popup show.

I have tried setTimeout for this.

```
            obj = JSON.parse(evt.data);

            if(obj.Addition=="0"){if(flag == 0){
               flag = 1;                    
               interval = setInterval(function(){
               $('div#popup2').show();
               }, 15000);                  
            }
            }

            else
            {
                clearInterval(interval);

                flag = 0;
            }
```

This way doesn't work because when Addition=1 it goes to else condition but when the machine is idle no data is coming from the server so technically no "obj.Addition" So I want to check the variables I am changing like smallCount ..If this variable get incremented then then the popup show

Comment: try removing =="0" in your condition

Comment: then no popup at all

Comment: What is the default value of obj.Addition?

Comment: default is not given. From server a default value is not given .. at start its sending as o and then if user add something sends Addition=1

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by clearing out the interval inside the same loop and again added the seInterval in the next condition as well
That way it would first clearoutInterval and then again set  Interval and so on

```
            if(obj.Addition=="0")
            {
                console.log(obj.Addition);
                clearInterval(interval);

                if(flag == 0){
                    flag = 1;                    
                interval = setInterval(function(){
                    $('div#popup2').show();

                }, 25000);                  
                }
            } 

            else 
            {
                console.log(obj.Addition);

                clearInterval(interval);
                interval = setInterval(function(){
                    $('div#popup2').show();

                }, 25000);       
                flag = 0;
            }
```